# Extract Detected Face Region from GMS Vision Face Detection Pipeline

Tags: android, surfaceview, face-detection, android-camera2

What is the recommended way to extract the actual pixels represented by the `Face` objects detected through the Android `gms.vision.face.*` packages?

I am working with the `FaceTracker` sample code from [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples/FaceTracker) for retrieving video frames from the device camera, and running them through face detection.

The pipeline attaches a `Face Detector` to a `CameraSource` which receives `Frame`s from a `SurfaceView` object. The Face Detector creates `Face` objects for each detected face. However, as far as I can tell, `Face` objects do not hold the underlying pixels that the face encompasses. I would like to store the detected face for future verification.

One possible solution (as far as I can tell) would be to receive a frame from the `SurfaceView`, hold on to that buffer, call the face detection on the single `Frame`, then use the `Face` objects returned to extract the pixels. However, I do not know enough about the implementation details to guess at the possible overhead of making a call with a single frame (model initialization, etc.). I'm re-familiarizing myself with Java after 10 years away, which means I'm also a bit slow grasping the code I'm reading :)

Any preferred solutions out there?

Comment: You can't receive frames, or anything else, from SurfaceView. It's a producer-consumer pair, where the producer (Surface) lives in the app, and the consumer is the system compositor (SurfaceFlinger). So I'm not quite sure what your current setup does. cf. https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Here is the image that I was describing, for clarification: https://developers.google.com/vision/images/face-tracker-pipeline.png

Comment: See a suggested approach here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32299947/mobile-vision-api-concatenate-new-detector-object-to-continue-frame-processing/32314136#32314136

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly the conclusion I came to, and have just finished implementing. It's good to have the independent validation, though! I wish I had been able to find it in the first place.

Comment: Can you post as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: any approach???