# Face detection on partial frame in Google Mobile Vision for Android

Tags: android, face-detection, google-vision, android-vision

Can anyone recommend an approach to specify a subset of a frame for face detection? This could be for a fixed area, say one quadrant of the frame, throughout the face tracking - so not dynamic per frame. In my case I only need to scan a fixed part of the frame and am interesting in improving performance.

Limiting tracking to prominent-face-only is not an option as I need to track multiple faces and cropping each frame before sending to detector is too slow. My hope is to achieve something like this:

```
// Send entire frame, but specify subset for detection
detector.receiveFrame(fullFrame, sub_x, sub_y, sub_width, sub_height)
```

Or when creating a frame:

```
// Create a partial frame from a full frame during frame building
Frame.Builder().setImageData(fullFrame_byteBuffer, sub_x, sub_y, sub_width, sub_height, format)
```

Am I missing an option to do this within the SDK, or might there be a better approach than doing a copy/cropping operation on the full frame?

Thanks

**Update**: I understand that this feature is present in the underlying Pittpatt implementation as `ppr_set_search_region(context, x1, y1, x2, y2)` - Might Google make this available on Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently possible. While [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35509532/2202359) is in response to dynamically limiting the detection area for bar codes, the answer seems to state categorically that limiting detection area is not currently supported.