# How to crop only face detection as a Bitmap part and display result?

Tags: java, android, image-processing, camera, android-camera

I'm Implementing [google-vision face tracker](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples/FaceTracker).

I have seen some stackoverflow implementation([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43632752/crop-face-from-the-camerasource)) to create face-bitmap and this is my result:

**Facedetection and Bitmap**

```
class MyFaceDetector extends Detector<Face> {

private Detector<Face> mDelegate;

MyFaceDetector(Detector<Face> delegate) {
    mDelegate = delegate;
}


public SparseArray<Face> detect(Frame frame) {

    YuvImage yuvImage = new YuvImage(frame.getGrayscaleImageData().array(), ImageFormat.NV21, frame.getMetadata().getWidth(), frame.getMetadata().getHeight(), null); // Create YUV image from byte[]
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    yuvImage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, frame.getMetadata().getWidth(), frame.getMetadata().getHeight()), 100, byteArrayOutputStream);// Convert YUV image to Jpeg
    byte[] jpegArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(jpegArray, 0, jpegArray.length); // Convert Jpeg to Bitmap

    Frame outputbmp =new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(bmp).setRotation(Frame.ROTATION_270).build();

    //part of image processing
    //...
    //part of image processing

        double heartRateFrequency = Fft.FFT(arrayGreen, heartRateFrameLength, finalSamplingFrequency);
        double battitialminuto=(int)ceil(heartRateFrequency*60);
        double heartRate1Frequency = Fft.FFT(arrayRed, heartRateFrameLength, finalSamplingFrequency);
        double breath1=(int)ceil(heartRate1Frequency*60);
        if((battitialminuto > 10 || battitialminuto < 24) )
        {
            if((breath1 > 10 || breath1 < 24)) {

                bufferAvgBr = (battitialminuto+breath1)/2;

            }
            else{

                bufferAvgBr = battitialminuto;
            }
        }
        else if((breath1 > 10 || breath1 < 24)){

            bufferAvgBr = breath1;
        }

        Breath=(int)bufferAvgBr;
    }

    else {
        // do nothing
    }

    return mDelegate.detect(outputbmp);
}

public boolean isOperational() {
    return mDelegate.isOperational();
}

public boolean setFocus(int id) {
    return mDelegate.setFocus(id);
}
}
```

Here there is FaceTrackerActivity class:

```
private void createCameraSource() {
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    detector = new FaceDetector.Builder(context)
            .setClassificationType(FaceDetector.ALL_CLASSIFICATIONS)
            .setMode(FaceDetector.ACCURATE_MODE)
            .setLandmarkType(FaceDetector.ALL_LANDMARKS)
            .build();
    MyFaceDetector myFaceDetector = new MyFaceDetector(detector);

    detector.setProcessor(
            new MultiProcessor.Builder<>(new GraphicFaceTrackerFactory())

                    .build());

    if (!detector.isOperational()) {

        Log.w(TAG, "Face detector dependencies are not yet available.");
    }

    mCameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(context, detector)
            .setRequestedPreviewSize(640, 480)
            .setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)
            .setRequestedFps(30.0f)
            .build();
```

And here there is a part that where I would to put Breath resulting from MyFaceDetection class:

```
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mPreview = (CameraSourcePreview) findViewById(R.id.preview);
        mGraphicOverlay = (GraphicOverlay) findViewById(R.id.faceOverlay);
        info3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info3);
        displayInfo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.display);
displayInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

             info3.setText("result"+ Breath);   
        });
```

I am a beginner and I do not understand why there is no result. I'm not sure I'm making a mistake in calculating the Bitmap image or calling up the Breath result but compiling I have no errors so I can not find the problem. Could someone direct me to the right path?