# Mobile Vision API new detector frame get Bitmap Image

Tags: android, dlib

I know similar Question has been asked Before:-
[Mobile Vision API - concatenate new detector object to continue frame processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32299947/mobile-vision-api-concatenate-new-detector-object-to-continue-frame-processing/32314136#32314136)

I am receiving the frame but when I call frame.getBitmap() it returns a null object.
I want to use this bitmap in https://github.com/tzutalin/dlib-android-app
 (Android dlib Library) FaceDet function.

Comment: Do you have any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

According to Mobile Vision API documentation, `Frame` object has method `getBitmap()` but it's clearly stated that

> getBitmap()
>   Returns the bitmap which was specified in creating this frame, or null if no bitmap was used to create this frame.

If you really want to get Bitmap object, you will have to create it yourself. One options is by `getGrayscaleImageData()` method on `Frame` object.
If there are some bytes in returned `ByteBuffer`, you can convert it to `Bitmap`.

Firstly you must create `YuvImage` using byte array from your `getGrayscaleImageData()` result. It's a mandatory step because byte array have image in [YUV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV)/[YCbCr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr) color space, encoded in [NV21](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat.html#NV21) format. So first line will look like this:

```
YuvImage yuvImage = new YuvImage(frame.getGrayscaleImageData().array(), ImageFormat.NV21, width, height, null);
```

`width` and `height` can be extracted from frame by `getMedatada().getHeight()` / `getMedatada().getWidth()` methods.

Then you can use `ByteArrayOutputStream` to quickly compress your `YuvImage` object.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
yuvImage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, width, height), 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
```

From there you can convert it to byte array again to finally use it in `BitmapFactory`.

```
byte[] jpegArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(jpegArray, 0, jpegArray.length);
```

I know that it's alot of code comparing to simple `getBitmap()` method usage, but it will do the job if you really need bitmap in that kind of situation.