# How to create a view like this?

Tags: android, android-camera

I am developing an application for scanning code on a scratch card, I do not know how to create a view like this and only scan the scratch card code in that view. I tried it but it scanned all over the screen and I just wanted to scan in a small frame[image: card scan image]

Comment: add dark overlay on everything except the part you want to be totally transparent. What exactly is a problem?

Comment: Not only that, I want the camera to scan only in bright areas

Comment: then you will have to cut that area from the view, and pass the images to your scanning code

Comment: Thanks for your enthusiasm, this problem is very difficult to describe, I have a list of similar tags, I scanned the number on the card, but when scanned it scanned the cards around it, so I Just want to do the view of the camera only scanning one card at a time

Comment: I found the answer in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32299947/mobile-vision-api-concatenate-new-detector-object-to-continue-frame-processing/43915078#4391507

Answer (score 0):

you can use OpenCv:

https://opencv.org/platforms/android/

example:

https://medium.com/easyread/integrating-your-android-app-with-opencv-library-266b2ea913d3

Comment: Can you describe more clearly? I want my camera to be scanned only on the small area of ​​the light

Comment: i'm not profesional in openCv. but i know some library to work width openCv:
https://github.com/jhansireddy/AndroidScannerDemo
https://github.com/aashari/android-opencv-camera-scanner