# Custom Detector implementation using Vision API

Tags: android, opencv, android-camera2, android-vision, vision-api

How do i create a custom Detector like FaceDetector and BarcodeDetector in Mobile vision API?

I am building a project to perform hand segmentation using color masks, i have the logic implemented in opencv.
I want to integrate that logic in using the vision api by implementing a custom Detector interface for hand segmentation.

Also, the detect(Frame) returns a SparseArray<> if you could shed some light on how to create that sparse array, it would be of great help

I visited [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32299947/mobile-vision-api-concatenate-new-detector-object-to-continue-frame-processing/32314136#32314136) thread but i don't want to wrap the Face detector as i have no use for it.